# TS2307 Cannot find a module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Angular 2 using their quick start guide, tour of heroes and the style guide. But instead of following it to the letter I'm trying to adapt it to a little project of mine. This is probably a very dumb mistake but I'm a little uncomfortable with how Angular 2 manages imports and exports.

I'm getting the following error on `NPM start`.

[image]

I'm trying to import a User service and user model from the shared folder withing the User folder module, my structure looks like so:

[image]

And my code looks like this:

[image]

I know what the error means, it is right there after all; the module cannot be found but I have tried `.user/shared`, `../shared` and `/users/shared` but nothing works. I don't think it matters but each module has a shared folder, my code is based on this example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#application-structure

```
app/heroes/heroes.component.ts
```

Any pointers to solve this would be awesome.

Edit: Modified as suggested with a index.ts under the shared folder. But now the app won't load properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `index.ts` (barrel) file in the `shared` directory, that exports the files from the shared directory

index.ts

```
export * from './user.model';
export * from './mock-users';
export * from './user.service';
```

Comment: It seems to compile but now the app won't load (it was doing it before) I have updated the OP, in case you can tell me if I'm ignoring something vital. In any case thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: I don't use SystemJS, so I'm not sure how it handles barrels. If it doesn't work, then just import the files directly, instead of from the barrel, i.e `import { User } from './shared/user.model'`

Comment: Yeah looking at the image, it doesn't look like it's properly handling the barrel, even though the TypeScript compile handles, the module loading system isn't. I haven't used SystemJS since I started learning Angular, so I don't remember if I've ever used barrels before with it. I know webpack handles then fine

Comment: I deleted the barrel and used the syntax you provided and it works now. I do wonder why though, I guess I'll be looking into it later but for now thanks! Do you know why my original import statement was failing? Was it caused by the ./shared ? I though he would be able to find the folder because shared was inside user

Comment: Because there's no shared.ts file. When you import, you are importing a file. Barrels allow you do list all the files to export from a folder so you _can_ use that folder-only syntax